# Convergent series almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory

My question is :

> Suppose
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E|X_{n}|^{a(n)}<\infty$$, where sequence
>   $1<a(n)\leq2$ for all $n$. Then,
>   $$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} E|X_{n}|^2<\infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $\sum b_i$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_i=0$. Thus there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $E|X_n|<1$. But numbers less than $1$ satisfy $x^a<x^b$ when $a>b$, so for all but finitely many terms incrementing the exponent decreases the sum, and you can (when looking at convergence) always discard finitely many terms. So

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty E|X_n|^2\leq\sum_{n=N}^\infty E|X_n|^{a_n}<\infty$$